# ng-repeat does not get updated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am struggling with a an issue that I have with angularjs and ng-repeat, I have a table which is generated by ng-repeat:

```
<div>
    <select ng-model="item" ng-controller="dropdown"
        ng-change="update(item)">
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    </select>
    <table ng-controller="repeatTest">
        <tr>
            <td>name</td>
            <td>family name</td>
            <td>score</td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.familyName }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.score }}</td>

        </tr>


    </table>


</div>
```

and my js code is as follows:

```
 var app = angular.module("myModule", []);

 app.service('sharedService', function() {


    this.list = [];

 });
app.controller('dropdown', function($scope, sharedService) {
$scope.update = function(item) {
    if (item == "volvo") {
        sharedService.list = [ {
            name : 'A',
            familyName : 'AA',
            score : '10'
        }, {
            name : 'B',
            familyName : 'BB',
            score : '5'
        } ];

        $scope.list = sharedService.list;
        console.log($scope.list);
    } else {
        sharedService.list = [ {
            name : 'zzz',
            familyName : 'zzz',
            score : '100'
        }, {
            name : 'zz',
            familyName : 'zz',
            score : '70'
        } ];
        $scope.list = sharedService.list;
    }
}

});
app.controller('repeatTest', function($scope, sharedService) {
sharedService.list = [ {
    name : 'xxx',
    familyName : 'xxx',
    score : 'xxx'
}, {
    name : 'xx',
    familyName : 'xx',
    score : 'xx'
} ];

$scope.list = sharedService.list;

});
```

Now my problem is the table si generated at the page load and never change again when I change the select box though it should because I bind the table to the list which is defined in scope and I assume whenever scope changes table should be affected as well. Can anyone help?

Comment: and where is `ng-controller="repeatTest"` defined?

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski sorry I forgot to put that please see the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two controllers for your example.

Just assign the dropdown controller to your parent div and remove the repeatTest controller. Something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="dropdown">
  <select ng-model="item" ng-change="update(item)">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </select>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>family name</td>
      <td>score</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
      <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.familyName }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.score }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

So, if you have the same controller for handling both select and table you don't need to watch the list variable in your services for changes.

You can solve in this way or implementing events, but i think this is the easily one.

Here a jsbin of the correct code: http://jsbin.com/sivapa/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thanks but this is a small example of a big scenario so what I need is to handle this problem with two controllers, do you have any idea why my approach does no work?

Comment: Yes, your approach doesn't work because you need to watch changes of list variable in other controller (your repeatTest). So you need to inject $scope and add this line after $scope.list = sharedService.list:


`$scope.watch(function() {
  return sharedService.list;
}, function(newVal) {
  $scope.list = newVal;
});`

this should work ;)

Comment: I've been updated the demo on jsbin for better explain, here the link: [http://jsbin.com/sivapa/edit?html,js,console,output](http://jsbin.com/sivapa/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

You have two scopes, one for each controller. By assigning $scope.list you are in effect passing the list by reference to each controller. So you should either clean and recreate the array without reassigning `$scope.list` or `sharedService.list`, or you could:

Add

```
$scope.sharedService = sharedService;
```

on both controllers and use `ng-repeat="item in sharedService.list"` instead, and you will get your updates.

The reason your current solution is not working is because you are creating a new array each time you call update. This means the other controller's list will still maintain a reference to the original/previous array.

An example of avoiding creating a new array each time:

```
var result = [];
if (item == "volvo") {
    result = [ {
        name : 'A',
        familyName : 'AA',
        score : '10'
    }, {
        name : 'B',
        familyName : 'BB',
        score : '5'
    } ];
} else {
    result = [ {
        name : 'zzz',
        familyName : 'zzz',
        score : '100'
    }, {
        name : 'zz',
        familyName : 'zz',
        score : '70'
    } ];
}

//Clear array
sharedService.list.splice(0,sharedService.list.length);
//Copy values from result into existing array
sharedService.list.push.apply(sharedService.list, result);
```

Please note this is untested. And you'd also have to do the initial assignment of $scope.list somewhere.

Comment: If @Troels is correct you might also be able to get around the problem by using `Array.splice()` to replace the contents of the array instead of replacing the array with a new array. This would result in the array reference staying the same.

Comment: so you mean by this $scope.list I am updating the reference so if I wanna update the value of the $scope.list what should I do?

Comment: Never set the value of sharedService.list (using the assignment operator =) outside of sharedService. And in sharedService do it only once (as you already are). Instead of creating a new array, clear the exsiting one and push in the new values.

Answer (score 1):

The 'repeatTest' controller doesn't have any way of knowing that the service data has changed...  unless you tell it to watch for that.  Try this version of that controller:

```
 app.controller('repeatTest', function($scope, sharedService) {

   $scope.list = sharedService.list;

   $scope.$watch(function() {
       return sharedService.list;
     },
     function(o, n) {
       if (o != n) $scope.list = n
     });
 });
```

Also, since your dropdown controller doesn't directly affect the list in repeatTest, you don't need to update $scope.list in that controller:

```
app.controller('dropdown', function($scope, sharedService) {
   $scope.update = function(item) {
     console.log(item);
     if (item == "volvo") {
       sharedService.list = [{
         name: 'A',
         familyName: 'AA',
         score: '10'
       }, {
         name: 'B',
         familyName: 'BB',
         score: '5'
       }];
     } else {
       sharedService.list = [{
         name: 'BMW',
         familyName: 'Germany',
         score: '100'
       }, {
         name: 'Frari',
         familyName: 'America',
         score: '100'
       }];
     }
   }
   // Do a little initialization
   $scope.item="volvo";
   $scope.update($scope.item);
 });
```

Here's a plunk:  http://plnkr.co/edit/42snC2WyfdKfNzrIKA0o

Comment: Thanks now I am confused from what I learnt in angular though I am beginner when we assign a variable to the scope it is accessible everywhere am I right? if yes then any update to that variable should be visible to the module!!! can u explain a ltl bit more?

Comment: Yes, but you are not updating $scope.list in repeatTest when you call update. And since you are changing the reference, not the value, it will not work. Read this page if you are not strong on reference vs value: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm